# extract text data using regexp in MATLAB

Tags: regex, matlab

I'm dealing with extracting visibility data in METAR(airport weather observation data).

Visibility is a 4 digit(0~9) data, and can also be expressed as'CAVOK' when visibility is good.

but it's quite tricky to use regexp. (METAR data have many variations.)

Data sample(MET_VIS) below:

```
201903072300 METAR RKPC 072300Z 17003KT 110V210 CAVOK 05/02 Q1026 NOSIG=
201903062000 METAR RKPC 062000Z 33018G29KT 4000 BR FEW012 SCT025 08/04 Q1018 WS R13 R31 NOSIG=
201903062200 METAR RKPC 062200Z 33015KT 290V350 9999 SCT030 07/03 Q1019 NOSIG=
201903080000 METAR RKPC 080000Z 29002KT CAVOK 08/02 Q1027 NOSIG=
```

I want to extract CAVOK, 4000, 9999, CAVOK on each line.

I tried but this code doesn't work with line 3 :( It returns blank.

```
regexp(MET_VIS(i),'((?<=KT\s)\d{4})|CAVOK','match')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The third value does not end on KT. What you might do is use another positive lookbehind to check if the string before it ends on KT and match a range of matching 7 times A-Z0-9 followed by a whitespace char after it.

Then you either match 4 digits or CAVOK using an alternation `(?:\d{4}|CAVOK)` or else you could match CAVOK anywhere in the string.

Add a word boundary after it to prevent the match being part of a larger word.

```
(?:(?<=KT\s)|(?<=KT [A-Z0-9]{7}\s))(?:\d{4}|CAVOK)\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iS4Yq3/1)

Answer (score 0):

You could also make an assumption about the range of "words" from the end your target should be allowed to occur in. For example:

```regex
/\b(?:\d{4}|CAVOK)\b(?=(?: \S+){3,9}$)/gm
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SLDowX/1).

Here we're looking for a four-digit number or the phrase CAVOK only, if it is followed by 3 to 9 non-space substrings of variable length until the end of the line.